# Is checkboxes checked or not?

Tags: php, forms

Need som serious help!

```
<?php
$php1 = !isset($_GET['php1']);
$php2 = !isset($_GET['php2']);
$php3 = !isset($_GET['php3']);
$php4 = !isset($_GET['php4']);
$php5 = !isset($_GET['php5']);

  if ($php1 == 'one' && $php2 == 'two' && $php5 == 'five') {
    echo "<h2>R</h2>WRONG";
  } else {
    echo "<h2>R</h2>CORRECT";
  }
?>
```

HTML

```
<form action="One.php" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="php1" value="one"> q1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="php2" value="two"> q1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="php3" value="three"> q1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="php4" value="four"> q1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="php5" value="five"> q1<br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Send!">
</form>
```

If all checkboxes are empty, there will be a message saying that. How do I do it?

If I dont check any boxes, it tells me the answers are correct. That's wrong.

Comment: you fill `$php1` with a boolean, and then check it as a string... what are you trying to do... ?

Comment: What kind of message? A javascript message?

Comment: You are not using radiobuttons, you are using checkboxes. Just thought you should know

Comment: Its a question-form. If php1 2 and 5 is checked its correct, otherwise its wrong. But when every radiobutton is not checked it says that its correct.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that UN-CHECKED Checkboxes are not even sent to the PHP script `$_POST`/`$_GET` by the browser.

So there existance is normally all you need to know.

First you must check that they were passed to the script and then check its value, otherwise you will receive `undefined index` errors for each checkbox that was not checked by the user

```
if (isset($_GET['php1']) && $_GET['php1'] != '' ) {
```

Although as the checkbox called `php1` can only be set to the value you give it, its value can be assumed and all you need to do is

```
if (isset($_GET['php1']) ) {
    // php1 was checked
```

Also `isset()` will test more than one variable exists using an AND. So you could write your code as

```
if ( isset($_GET['php1'], $_GET['php2'], $_GET['php5']) ) {
    echo "<h2>Resultat</h2>Du svarade rätt på frågan";
} else {
    echo "<h2>Resultat</h2>Du svarade fel på frågan";
}
```

Comment: OP: *"Please not that the method of stringing along with comma-separated values, will not work with `empty()`"* - lol

Comment: True, but who said anything about `empty()` Ralph @Fred-ii-

Comment: Errr... I have *lol!* - You know.... some think they can do anything with functions they think will "function" correctly. Not always the case.

Comment: True, we all function of a different plain

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
If(isset($_GET['php1'])){
  $php1 = 1;
}else{
  $php1 = 0;
}
If(isset($_GET['php2'])){
  $php2 = 1;
}else{
  $php2 = 0;
}
If(isset($_GET['php3'])){
  $php3 = 1;
}else{
  $php3 = 0;
}
If(isset($_GET['php4'])){
  $php4 = 1;
}else{
  $php4 = 0;
}
If(isset($_GET['php5'])){
  $php5 = 1;
}else{
  $php5 = 0;
}    

if ($php1 && $php2 && $php5) {
   echo "<h2>Resultat</h2>Du svarade rätt på frågan";
} else {
   echo "<h2>Resultat</h2>Du svarade fel på frågan";
}
```

Try this.

Each php variable will have the value of 1 or 0 (true/false). Thus the if only needs to check it if it is or not.

Comment: Will generate undefined index warnings all over the place.

Comment: @RiggsFolly True. But it would have worked :-), updated the answer without errors :-)

Comment: I'd cut that code down with either a case or ternary

Comment: @bamtastix could you please accept the answer then? Varsågod!

Comment: Or use the fact that `isset()` can test more than one variable ... [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36986259/2310830) @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Fred-ii- I thought of ternary, but then again you need to walk before you run. It's better to have a code that you can understand than a short and compact one.

Comment: @RiggsFolly True, yet... the OP might think that they can use it with `empty()` which would fail.

Comment: @Andreas It's an option they can later look into ;-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly nice one! Did not see that code before.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if you only knew what his questions in the original post was about.... :-) hint google translate

Comment: @Andreas yeah... TBH, I have a hard time wrapping my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $php1 = !isset($_GET['php1']);
> ```

This means $php1 is either true or false. If you want the value of php1 get parameter then remove isset cover, just

```
$_GET['php1'];
```

isset is used to check whether the variable exist or not **after that use $_GET['php1'];**

Comment: Will generate undefined index warnings all over the place.

Comment: Yes, because I tried to tell how to get checkbox value as he was doing incorrectly by comparing string to boolean. Anyways thanks, I updated the answer.